# The else statement is connecting to my other elif statement (python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import random    
import asyncio    
import aiohttp
import discord
import json
from discord import Game
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

TOKEN = ''

client = discord.Client()

botnum = 0

@client.event
    async def on_ready():
    print('Online and Ready to Play!')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="With Emotions"))
    print('------')



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global botnum
# we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
elif message.content.startswith('Peribot'): ### Updated to elif which is more acceptable
    msg = "I'm Busy! D:<".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
elif botnum == 20: ### forgot a ":" and Updated to elif which is more acceptable
    msg = "You Clods are so loud!".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    botnum = 0 ### you were comparing and not setting botnum to 0
else:
    botnum += 1 ### This will add 1 to the preexisting number of botnum
elif message.content.startswith('info'): ### Updated to elif which is more acceptable
    msg = "Created by Popleoma with the intent of being a fun bot. Commands are Peribot, info, and more to come!".format(message)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
client.run("")
```

Whenever I add the last elif statement it connects to the previous else statment. I have tried adding enter's between them but it keeps connecting. Here is what my text editor puts https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6pGl.jpg . I need a way for it not to connect as when it does connect it doesn't run my code it just crashes python compiler.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect"? Why do you have an `elif` after an `else`? What is that `elif` supposed to be a part of?

Comment: Indentation looks suspect to me. Does it actually run?

Comment: all the elif parts are all wrongly indented till the end.

Comment: Hmm, looking at your editor screen shot I think that "connection" is just the code editor attempting to make sense of your statements. The final elif looks to be an orphan, it's not connected to anything in fact. Should it perhaps be a simple If?

Comment: or maybe the last elif should be poisitioned before the else not after it?

Comment: Please write the code exactly as it is. Currently it does not run because of wrong indentation. Indentation is very important in Python, so it may as well be cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, the Python runner thing is going to have a problem with that code.

Comment: `elif` and `if` are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you did not indent any of your elif statements to line up with your if statement, this is how python knows to "connect" statements/blocks of code. It should look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global botnum
# we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith('Peribot'): 
        msg = "I'm Busy! D:<".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    elif botnum == 20: 
        msg = "You Clods are so loud!".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
        botnum = 0 
    elif message.content.startswith('info'): 
        msg = "Created by Popleoma with the intent of being a fun bot. Commands are Peribot, info, and more to come!".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    else:
        botnum += 1 

client.run("")
```

In addition to this you put an elif block after an else statement which will not work. Here is a tutorial on python indentation for future reference:
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: Also for future reference, to avoid downvotes you should refer to the python runner thing as a compiler :)

Comment: The indention in my post was different than the indention in my code, sorry. What I didn't know is that elif had to come before and else. A follow up question would be is it possible to have two else statments?

Comment: No python would not allow you to do this as there would be no way to know which else statement to execute. Why would you want two else statements you could just add another elif statement or add the line you want on your other else statement underneath botnum += 1

Comment: Ahh I see, also thank you for telling me what the compiler is called. I am sorry for being so ignorant of the language.

Comment: For future reference, although I don't mind answering beginner questions a lot of people on SO do not like answering questions if people have not decided to learn the basics or read pythons documentation. This would be a good place: